# How to create AWS Elastic BeanStalk in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am finding available modules in Ansible on the website quite limited in terms of what is available for creating and configuring AWS Elastic BeanStalk. What I did find was the following module aws_elasticbeanstalk_app which allows for the creation of the application.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_elasticbeanstalk_app_module.html

However, I fails to see how elements available in Beanstalk such as Software, Platform, ELB, Monitoring, Subnets, EC2 Capacity and rolling Updates to name but a few.

Should my Ansible module definition call a separate json file containing this level of information? I am thinking of EB CLI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html.

I suppose this query is leading in best practice and get an idea of those engineers who have faced this same question and applied a solution that was a successful implementation.

Thanks in advance for your response should you wish to leave one.

Comment: The other option is to use [cloudformation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cloudformation_module.html) module, and define your EB env though cloudformation templates.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin I am attempting to avoid CloudFormation. Do you think its worth calling the CloudFormation template via an Ansible Module? I think that might be worth a go.

Comment: Hi. Its an option to consider. If the other modules provide limited EB support, cloudformation would give you full set of possibilities. Thus, it maybe worth considering if nothing else seem suitable.